# How to traverse all the paths between two specified vertices in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given the graph is a directed graph. I want to find the most efficient algorithm.
Thanks for help!
Maybe we could do it in O(V+E)

Comment: In the worst case, there would be exponentially many paths, as function of `V`. Traversing them all in `O(V+E)` is a tad optimistic.

Comment: [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to the rescue !...

Comment: @Rerito No. Floyd Warshall is All to all shortest path, while this question is about one two one all paths.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Exponential paths]

Consider this graph. The number of paths between s and t is 2^(number of diamonds), where each diamond is a rectangle. Since, 3*(no. of diamonds) + 1 = n, no. of diamonds = (n-1)/3. So, there are 2^(n-1/3) paths between s and t.

This proves that your problem can never be done in linear time.